# Using Data Aggregated in Contact Builder in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I was just curious that in Marketing Cloud whenever we use a Contact in sending email, journey interactions or any other things, data is recorded for that Contact and it is visible in All Contact data tab. Is there any way to use this data directly?

Answer (score 0):

You check check under the history tab so see interactions and drill down to dates/journeys/activities. 
[image]

You can also view information about Journey Builder sends via tracking -> Journey Builder Sends[image]